# PHP fetch all results from table, not not fetch the same ID over and over?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

Results in DB:

```
TID - message
1 - hi
1 - bye
2 - hi 
2 - hi
2 - bye
```

Statement:

```
$new = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_posts ORDER BY pid ASC LIMIT 1");
```

I don't want to fetch the same ID twice, only once.

So it will fetch:

`1 - hi` and `2 - hi`.

How do I do so?

Comment: You need to run your queries in mysql client prior calling them from PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this works:

```
$new = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_posts GROUP BY pid ORDER BY pid ASC");
```

When tested in phpMyAdmin it returns:

```
PID - message
1   - hi
2   - hi
```

Answer (score 1):

thx for your comment, edited my post:

```
$new = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM mybb_posts GROUP BY pid ORDER BY pid");
```

or

```
$new = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(pid) FROM mybb_posts ORDER BY pid");
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Firstly, `DISTINCT(*)` doesn't work in MySQL, I have to use `DISTINCT *`. Moreover, if I execute it on a test database, I get `1 - bye`, `1 - hi`,  `2 - bye` and `2 - hi`, whereas the topic starter wants `1 - hi` and `2 - hi`.